# Component jquery fails to install with bower

Tags: jquery, angularjs, docker, bower

I'm trying to create a web project and I'm having trouble installing the dependencies. I'm getting the following error:

```
Running "bower_concat:all" (bower_concat) task
Fatal error: Component jquery not installed. Try bower install --save jquery
```

I'm building the project with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:8-alpine AS buildstep

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache git

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
COPY .bowerrc /root/.bowerrc
RUN npm run build
```

The package.json file has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "express": "4.16.0",
    "request": "<=2.81.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "1.8.2",
    "grunt": "1.0.2",
    "grunt-cli": "1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "3.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-include-source": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-sass": "2.1.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "3.0.1",
    "grunt-bower-concat": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1"
  }
```

While my bower.json has the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "angular": "1.4.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.5.0",
    "angular-cache": "4.3.2",
    "angular-growl-v2": "0.7.5",
    "angular-jwt": "0.0.9",
    "angular-mocks": "1.4.5",
    "angular-xeditable": "0.8.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "ng-busy": "0.2.0",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.9",
    "ng-table": "1.0.0",
    "ng-showdown": "1.0.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "angular-md5": "0.1.8",
    "angular-strap": "2.3.5",
    "Chart.js": "1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "0.13.4",
    "angular-swagger-ui": "0.2.7",
    "font-awesome-animation": "0.0.7",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.5",
    "ngclipboard": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.19.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.8",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.2",
    "html2canvas": "^0.4.1",
    "papaparse": "4.2.0",
    "angular-moment": "^1.0.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.5"
  }
```

This has stopped working, apparently without any changed in the dependencies or the code, so I believe I could be a problem in the dependencies graph, although this is not the type of error that I would expect in that case.

Comment: bower has been considered as unstable and they suggest to migrate away toward yarn https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ this may fix your problem and wont take much time.

Comment: That is something probably interesting to consider, but to do that I need to be able to install the packages with bower, and that is not working. If I try to do that, trying to install only the package in the bower.json file I end up with the error: ```bower canvg#1.5.3                              ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.5.3``` It also says that there are```Available versions in https://github.com/shprink/canvg.git: 1.3.0``` but I'm not fixing that dependency so I'm not sure if that will work